# How to define a mixin with multiple json creators for a type hierachy in jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to derserialize some hamcrest matchers using jackson. Therefore I have created the following mixin:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = HasPropertyWithValue.class, name = "hasPropertyWithValue"),
        @Type(value = IsEqual.class, name = "equalTo") })
public class HamcrestMixIn {

    @JsonCreator
    public static <T> HasPropertyWithValue<T> hasPropertyWithValue(@JsonProperty("property") String property,
            @JsonProperty("valueMatcher") Matcher<T> valueMatcher) {
        return new HasPropertyWithValue<>(property, valueMatcher);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static <T> IsEqual<T> isEqualTo(@JsonProperty("value") T value) {
        return new IsEqual<>(value);
    }
}
```

and registered this mixin in my spring boot app via declaring a bean with a `SimpleModule` containing this mixin only.

However when trying to deserialize this json:

```
{
    "_type": "hasPropertyWithValue",
    "property": "foo",
    "valueMatcher": {
        "_type": "equalTo",
        "value": "bar"
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.hamcrest.beans.HasPropertyWithValue` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 3, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1909)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:408)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1420)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:220)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:263)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4730)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3714)
```

How do I need to change the mix in to construct

```
HamcrestMixIn.hasPropertyWithValue("foo", HamcrestMixIn.isEqualTo("bar"))
```

based on the above json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mixin class for every subtype is required:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = HasPropertyWithValue.class, name = "hasPropertyWithValue"),
        @Type(value = IsEqual.class, name = "equalTo")})
public class HamcrestMixIn {

    public abstract static class HasPropertyWithValueMixIn<T> {
        @JsonCreator
        public HasPropertyWithValueMixIn(@JsonProperty("property") String property,
                @JsonProperty("valueMatcher") Matcher<T> valueMatcher) {
        }
    }

    public abstract static class IsEqualMixIn<T> {
        @JsonCreator
        public IsEqualMixIn(@JsonProperty("value") T value) {
        }
    }
}
```

All of those need to be registered separately in the jackson module:

```
module.setMixInAnnotation(IsEqual.class, IsEqualMixIn.class);
module.setMixInAnnotation(HasPropertyWithValue.class, HasPropertyWithValueMixIn.class);
module.setMixInAnnotation(Matcher.class, HamcrestMixIn.class);
```